Dynamic List in Excel
I'm new to Excel and I'm trying to create a table for some live reporting.
I use two columns for my final calcs and essentially I'm looking for a specific value U2 (can be multiple) in the range of A2:A500. Whenever there is a match I take the corresponding value from B2:B500 range.
SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$500=U2)*$B$2:$B$500)

The formula does exactly what I need, however, if there is less than 500 rows of data it is giving me the #VALUE! error
I've started looking for a way to make it dynamic so I tried to use the full column inseted, however it gave me the same error
SUMPRODUCT((A:A=U2)*B:B)

I also tried different varioations of the OFFSET function but none of them seem to work for me either.
Does it makes sense to use OFFSET for this purpose?
If not, is there any other function I can use to make my formula dynamic.

If there is any text in Column B it will error as you cannot multiply text.  So if you have a title in B1 it will error if included.  Also if B is filled with a formula that returns "" it sees that as text and will also error.

Make sure that you return 0 instead of "" in column B  and do not include the title cell in the range and it will work.

Or you can do =SUM(FILTER(B:B,A:A=U2))

I think its better to use a Structured Reference aka Tables and then use within the formula here. Like =SUM((Table1[Header]=U2)*Table1[Vals])

Please don't use OFFSET() or any volatile functions. any single threaded functions will gradually slow down the working functionality of Excel. Also using the whole range is not suggested here most of the time. But FILTER() function is helpful as suggested above by @ScottCraner Sir

Also have you tried looking into IFERROR() function. SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(($A$2:$A$500=U2)*$B$2:$B$500,0))
